# The relation between quasi-permutation matrix and permutation matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

We know that  a quasi-permutation matrix is a square matrix over the
complex numbers with non-negative integral trace.

Can anyone tell me why it is called "quasi-permutation matrix"? Is there any relation between quasi-permutation matrix and permutation matrix?

Comment: A permutation matrix satisfies the definition of a quasi-permutation matrix, since the entries of a permutation are zeros and ones.  Obviously the converse is not true, so the quasi-permutation matrices are a richer setting for finite groups to have matrix representations.  Are you with me so far?

Comment: @ hardmath  Your word is right. But I think there  maybe something special between  quasi-permutaion matrix and permutation matrix. Maybe it's just  a name ,so-so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to appreciate the choice of terminology is by looking back at the 1962 paper [Linear groups analogous to permutation groups](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ3_02%2FS1446788700027920a.pdf&code=ed87864a100a799691f4e05f6aebbcf2) by W.J. Wong, where [the concept is introduced](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ36_03%2FS0017089500030901a.pdf&code=e06486d4dc92ab375695a37a3d8fa71f):

> If $G$ is a finite linear group of degree $n$, that is, a finite group of automorphisms of an $n$-dimensional complex vector space (or, equivalently,
>   a finite group of non-singular matrices of order $n$ with complex coefficients),
>   I shall say that $G$ is a *quasi-permutation group* if the trace of every element of $G$ is a non-negative rational integer. The reason for this terminology is that, if $G$ is a permutation group of degree $n$, its elements, considered as acting on the elements of a basis of an $n$-dimensional complex vector space $V$, induce automorphisms of $V$ forming a group isomorphic to $G$. The trace of the automorphism corresponding to an element $x$ of $G$ is equal to the number of letters left fixed by $x$, and so is a non-negative integer. Thus, a permutation group of degree $n$ has a representation as a quasi-permutation group of degree $n$.

Although stated slightly differently than I did in my Comment, it provides the same essential justification for the terminology, anticipating that this more general framework for finite group representations (linear = using matrices) may share some nice properties with permutation groups.

Wong next states two properties of a permutation group $G$ of degree $n$:

- The order $|G|$ is a divisor of $n!$
- If $p$ is a prime number exceeding $\sqrt{n}$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is of elementary Abelian type.

The rest of the paper basically proves analogous statements about quasi-permutation groups:

> Theorem $1.\;\;$  The order of a quasi-permutation group $G$ of degree $n$ is a divisor of $n!$
>
> Theorem $2.\;\;$  The Sylow $p$-group of a quasi-permutation group of degree $n$ smaller than $p^2$ is of elementary Abelian type.

The closing paragraph of that paper summarizes the two results as showing that "any $p$-group which can be represented as a quasi-permutation group of degree $n$ can also be represented as a permutation group of degree n, provided that $p^2 \gt n$."  The paragraph then notes that the condition $p^2 \gt n$ cannot be omitted by giving the example of the quaternion group of order $8$, which has a representation as a quasi-permutation group of degree $4$, but none as a permutation group of degree $4$.

One might read this example as suggesting that generalizing to quasi-permutation groups allows for representations of smaller degree than permutation groups do, while still providing concrete opportunities for investigation.  Much of the subsequent research literature has compared the minimal degree $p(G)$ of a (faithful) representation of certain finite groups $G$ by permutation groups with the minimal degree $c(G)$ by quasi-permutation groups.  The introductory fact that permutation groups are quasi-permutation groups implies $c(G) \le p(G)$.

Finally we note that *quasi-permutation group* has to be understood in a slightly more permissive (artful?) spirit than *permutation group* is.  The product of two compatible sized permutation matrices is again a permutation matrix, but the product of two quasi-permutation matrices need not be a quasi-permutation matrix (though it will be *a posteriori* if both are elements of a quasi-permutation group).  For example:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix} $$

This last has trace $2i$, not an non-negative integer, so it is not a quasi-permutation matrix despite being the product of two quasi-permutation matrices.

Comment: @ hardmath  Thank you very much. I get some things about quasi-permutation matrix.

Comment: the trace of a permutation matrix is equal to the number of vector elements whose position/order remains unchanged

Comment: @phdmba7of12:  Yes, this is mentioned in the paragraph I quote above, from the paper by W. J. Wong (1962) which introduced the notion of *quasi-permutation groups*.